# Use same wamp server on two computers

Tags: mysql, localhost, wamp, local, lan

I have two computers. I have placed both computers in different rooms. 
I want to use 1 wamp server on both computers. I will install wamp on any computer then I want to access it from another computer. How can I do that?
Can you tell me how to connect these computers and how to use same wamp server.

Comment: Assuming they belong to the same network, your wamp server should be accessible through the host's IP. If you have a more specific problem, like giving access to your mysql database, please improve your question.

Comment: Its really not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to run one PC with WAMPServer on it as the Server and the other as a client?

Comment: I have a php script that I want to run on both computers but I want to use same MySQL server.